# Understaing Logic of HashMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;  
class TestCollection13{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();  

        hm.put(100,"Amit");  
        hm.put(101,"Vijay");  
        hm.put(102,"Rahul");  

        for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet()){  
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+m.getValue());  
        }  
    }  
}
```

in this above HaspMap program i can not understand the logic behind this for loop . why Map.Entry is needed and what is the function of entrySet() ?? 
help me regarding this please . thanks in advance

Comment: can you send me this link ?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop iterates over all the entries in the `HashMap`. The [`entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet()) will return *all* key-value pairs in the map.

`Map.Entry` is just the type of a key-value pair (just as `String` is a type).

Comment: `public class MyHash {
    public static void main(String a[]){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("first", "FIRST INSERTED");
        hm.put("second", "SECOND INSERTED");
        hm.put("third","THIRD INSERTED");
        System.out.println(hm);
        Set<String> keys = hm.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
            System.out.println("Value of "+key+" is: "+hm.get(key));
        }
    }
}` 
i can do this program by this way also .what is the difference between this two???.here we dont use Map.Entry for a key value pair ...